# Partition Negative and Positive in an Array in java

Tags: arrays

You are given an array of n integers, both negative and positive. You need to partition them into two different arrays without directly comparing any element to 0, 1, -1 or any other fixed value. Consider 0 as a positive number. If arr[0] is a positive number, then print all the positive numbers in the given order in the first line of output and then all the negative numbers in the given order in the second line of output, vice - versa.
Note:
If the array contains only positive numbers then print the positive numbers in the first line and in the second line print “Array doesn't have negative numbers”.
If the array contains only negative numbers then print the negative numbers in the first line and in the second line print “Array doesn't have positive numbers”.

Input: The input should be in the following format:
The first line should be the number of elements in the array.
The second line should be n elements of array space separated.

Output: The output should be in the following format:
If arr[0] is a negative number, then print all the negative numbers in the given order in the first line of output and then all the positive numbers in the given order in the second line of output, vice - versa.
Each element of each output line should be separated by a space.

Comment: To help better answer a question, you need to provide code/config snippets you tried, errors you got, and docs you looked up. Please consider improving your question. The question ideally should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding two numbers from which you can figure out which number is positive

```
int sum = s1 + s1; // 
 //eg 1+2=3 if sum is greater than both numbers , both are positive
if(sum>=s1 && sum>=s2 ){
   // Both are positive
}
//eg -1-2=-3 if sum is lesser than both numbers , both are negative
else if (sum<s1 && sum<s2){
  //Both are negative
}
/* 
 *If none of the above case don't pass, we can confirm that only one of
 * the number is negative ,so the lesser number is negative and other one 
 * is positive
*/
else if (s1<s2){
  // s1 is negative and s2 is positive
} 
else{
  // s2 is negative and s1 is positive
}
```